# Fetch not repeated rows in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, fetch

I would like to fetch a list from a query in Hibernate but without repeated elements.

Currently i have something like:

```
SELECT t FROM Table t join fetch t.list tl WHERE tl.userid=:userid AND tl.tableid=t.id
```

This works good! the problem its that it returns the same object as many times as userid its in tl

so lets say userid its found 3 times in tl i am getting:

```
T
  TL1
  TL2
  TL3
T
  TL1
  TL2
  TL3
T
  TL1
  TL2
  TL3
```

and i want to get:

```
T
  TL1
T
  TL2
T
  TL3
```

or just one:

```
T
  TL1
  TL2
  TL3
```

I guess its possible in Hibernate but havent manage it yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do write

```
SELECT  distinct t FROM Table t join fetch t .......
      -----^------
```

[HQL ORDER BY clause and DISTINCT clause](http://thecafetechno.com/tutorials/hibernate/hql-order-by-and-distinct-column-example/) will be helpful further.

Comment: That was easy, dint know the distinct stament was possible that implicit.
Thanks

Comment: Its not that much until we know it :) happens to every one glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use then [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
  SELECT DISTINCT t FROM Table t join fetch t.list tl WHERE tl.userid=:userid 
AND tl.tableid=t.id
```

It will give you result without the repeated values

Answer (score 0):

you could also try using Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY